# Efecto background y con card

Tags: html, css

Quiero lograr el efecto de card y background. Donde el background quede aproximadamente a mitad de la card. Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código HTML que tengo hasta el momento es este

```
<section class="seccion2">
  <div class="container pt-5">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px; ">
          <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
          <p>Este es un titulo corto muestral</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime pariatur earum, nesciunt veniam velit doloremque repudiandae, voluptatum culpa dolorum corporis a illum molestiae eos ducimus mollitia. Soluta qui mollitia odio!</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <p>Titulo simple</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum illo eius corrupti repudiandae rem maiores accusamus ut quod quibusdam earum officia rerum vitae incidunt aspernatur, pariatur dolorem sed quam minus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <p>Titulo simple</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum illo eius corrupti repudiandae rem maiores accusamus ut quod quibusdam earum officia rerum vitae incidunt aspernatur, pariatur dolorem sed quam minus.</p>
            </div>    <div class="col-lg-4">
              <p>Titulo simple</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum illo eius corrupti repudiandae rem maiores accusamus ut quod quibusdam earum officia rerum vitae incidunt aspernatur, pariatur dolorem sed quam minus.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

No tengo problemas con la estructura de la card ni con el contenido. El problema es que no consigo lograr el efecto. El CSS con el que he intentado resolverlo

```
.seccion2{
background: linear-gradient(180deg,transparent 50%, rgb(10, 10, 10) 50%);
}
```

> Podría incluir cualquier lenguaje que me pueda dar como resultado este efecto, siempre y cuando pueda aplicarlo en un sitio creado en php. Gracias

Así está actualmente
[image: 2]

Comment: Si publicaras todo tu css podría ayudarte, no es complicado, con un translateY(-50%) debería resolverse todo fácil.

Comment: Gracias @JaimeMenéndezÁlvarez , si efectivamente esto lo resolvió.

Answer (score 0):

creo que no entendi bien, estas intenando hacer que a la mitad del card
tenga otro color. Si es haci es de esta manera

```
div#card{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,white 50%,transparent 50%);
}
```

Para el texto solo busca los que están más abajo del la parte blanca y cambiarlas de color.

Si no es el resultado que deseabas avisáme.